# Graph API LocateDevice Action

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, intune

Using this query via Graph Explorer:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices/{managedDeviceId}/locateDevice
I've modified all permissions to the required permissions, in-fact I have allowed all permissions possible.
However when I run this I get a "resource not found" error.

I'm learning Graph API with 0 coding background other than some PowerShell knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error information `resource not found`, it seems that deviceId is not correct. You could use the [Get deviceManagement API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/intune_devices_devicemanagement_get) to list the vaild deviceId and try it again.

If it is also get the same result. You could have a try to use the  beta version [locateDevice action API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_devicefe_manageddevice_locatedevice). As I find that [locateDevice action API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_devicefe_manageddevice_locatedevice) is beta veraion.

> Important: APIs under the /**beta** version in Microsoft Graph are in preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

Comment: Thank you Tom! So I feel bad you had to point that out. I did try all three IDs available for devices - DeviceID, ObjectID, UniqueID. With the UniqueID I got a different error! "BadRequest". I've tried both beta and 1.0.